# can not able to use "Helori\LaravelSeo\SeoServiceProvider\Seo" in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use `helori/laravel-seo`. Getting Seo alias in web.php but When I am trying to use in controller

```
Seo::set('title', 'My home page title');
```

like this, it is giving

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Seo' not found

error. 
I have tried with

```
use \Helori\LaravelSeo\SeoServiceProvider\Seo;
```

Still having problem.

Answer (score -1):

you should set alias in your config/app.php

Comment: Yes I already used that. That is why if I set the values in web.php it is going to views. But cannot getting in controller.

Comment: <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Seo;
class YourController extends Controller
{

public function getSeo()
{
 Seo::set('description', "My home page description");
}

}

Comment: to get the value that set in controller to the blade,use below code in your blade <meta name="description" content="{{ Seo::get('description') }}" />

Comment: Hey! where did you return your blade from controller ?                                    
 return view('yourblade.php');

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry but not working. Blank page with an error on tab "woops! there was an error" Also the view source is blank.